# Make link during dynamically populating the table using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make the link from during dynamic populating the table using Jquery. I am populating the table data as

```
trHTML += 
        '<tr><td>'+ value['value1'] +
        '</td> <td>' + value['value2'] + 
        '</td> <td>' + value['value3'] + 
        '</td><td>'.html('<a href="' + "http://www.google.com/" + value['valueLink'] + '">' + "Link" + '</a>')+
        '</td></tr>';
```

But it gives error

> Uncaught TypeError: `"</td><td>`".html is not a function

Comment: Could you show the `value` object, because while string concatenation will work I'm sure there has to be a more efficient solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use `.html()` continue string concatenation.

```
'</td><td>' + '<a href="' + "http://www.google.com/" + value['valueLink'] + '">' + "Link" + '</a>'+
```

However, I would recommend you to create HTML using [jQuery( html, attributes )](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes) method for cleaner approach.

```
var tr = $("<tr>")
var anchor = $("<a>", {
    "href" : "http://www.google.com/" + value['valueLink'],
    "text" : "Link"
});
var td = $("<td>");
td.append(anchor);

tr.append(td);
```

Comment: Bingoooooooooooooooooo!.